# Trouble with opening a file with my iphone application

Tags: javascript, ios, command-line, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a IOS application created through phonegap framework. I have registered a particular file extension that my application can open. The problem now is that, when a user clicks on a file to open with my program, I need to handle that accordingly. How can my iphone application handle the case when the program is opened via clicking on the file? More specifically, I need the file location so I can read the file upon startup of my program. I thought I did this by creating a command line plugin, but I guess it doesn't work. I think its because, if my application was started already, it just starts at the point where it was left off, instead of restarting it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the handleOpenURL in AppDelegate.m. When file was opened, while app was in background, that function was called with the appropriate filePath.